# How to bold highlight duplicate rows excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which picks up duplicate rows, however I can not get the code to  highlight the duplicates in bold as well as deleting them at the same time.

```
Public Sub ProcessData()
Const TEST_COLUMN As String = "A" '<=== change to suit
Dim i As Long
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range

With ActiveSheet

    iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TEST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To iLastRow
        If .Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(A" & i & ":A" & iLastRow & "=A" & i & ")," & _
    "--(D" & i & ":D" & iLastRow & "=D" & i & ")," & _
    "--(F" & i & ":F" & iLastRow & "=F" & i & ")," & _
    "--(J" & i & ":J" & iLastRow & "=J" & i & ")," & _
        "--(K" & i & ":K" & iLastRow & "=K" & i & "))") > 1 Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = .Cells(i, "A").Resize(, 11)
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, .Cells(i, "A").Resize(, 11))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    **If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Delete.font.bold = true**


End With
```

End Sub

the example of the dataset and desired output can be seen in the following downloadable link below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7rhktg6b4nk6ig0/Bold_highlight_Duplicate%20.xlsm

any help would be very much appreciated.  Thank you.

*Edit:*

to clarify, this is how it should look like, just that input shall be deleted and the bold highlighting should appear in the output section:

[image]

Comment: why would you set them bold, if you want to delete them?! ahh - wait - you want to delete the `rng` with the union and set the other rng bold or the other way around - right?

Comment: The bold feature would allow me to see which of the same variable in column a (name) was duplicated and deleted. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I would like to delete (rng) and bold the duplicate row which was deleted. I hope this clarifies any misunderstanding with the representation of my problem.  Thank once again for your response and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `**If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Delete.font.bold = true**` use the following:

```
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
  with rng
   .Offset(.Areas(.Areas.Count).Rows(.Areas(.Areas.Count).Rows.Count).Row + 1).Font.Bold = True
   .Delete
  end with
End If
```

How this works?

Well, you could have setup the bold indicator while testing for duplicates, however you took a different approach, which does not allow that.

So, your `rng` is a multiarea selection.

You have to get to the last area, then to the last row of that area, and then retrieve the actual row you're in. Then add +1 for the space between. Now you know how many rows are covered by the input section + the gap to the output and you offset your selection by this count onto the output section.

However, there might be complications, depenting on your input/output - I tested this briefly on your example - worked. Still, I think it would be better to use a different kind of loop & duplicate detection.

Comment: Jook could you please show an example of a duplicate row detection macro that will detect for duplicate rows and highlight any duplicates? Thanks